# Validate phone number with Yup?

Tags: javascript, yup

I'm trying to validate a phone number with Yup:

```
phone: Yup.number()
  .typeError("That doesn't look like a phone number")
  .positive("A phone number can't start with a minus")
  .integer("A phone number can't include a decimal point")
  .min(8)
  .required('A phone number is required'),
```

`.min(8)` validates that the number is 8 or more. So simply entering `8` will pass. How can I make 8 characters required so `1000 0000` would pass?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Hi right now I'am solving same problem as you and I found possible solution.

**Validate phone number with string that matches Regex**

```
const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/

phoneNumber: Yup.string().matches(phoneRegExp, 'Phone number is not valid')
```

You can search for different Regex Expressions and validate it.
I've used Regex from this article https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/phone-number-regular-expression-validation/2204

Comment: matches(" ") is working for me, it is giving a warning as **Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** in react-native. Please help me

Comment: Sirisha I think its because your variable is not a string. Initialise your variable as empty string and then listen to onChanged event in TextInput.

Comment: why \\? worked for me only after removing redundant escapes.

Comment: `/^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ -]?)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ -]?)|([0-9]{2,4})[ -]?)*?[0-9]{3,4}[ -]?[0-9]{3,4}$/` worked best for me. @filippofilip your expression matches thing such as +32----------1111111

Comment: @LGenzelis I tried your regex -- but this allowed numbers with multiple + in the middle +32+232232232

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/regex-phone-number-validation-forked-h7bmxt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: LGenzelis - https://codesandbox.io/s/regex-flipflop-phone-number-validation-forked-u124dr

Comment: Flipflop -- https://codesandbox.io/s/regex-flipflop-phone-number-validation-forked-b3nh1h?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 56):

### **>. Update .<**

http://yup-phone.js.org/

I've created a [**`yup-phone`**](http://yup-phone.js.org/) module that uses `google-libphonenumber` which gives accurate validation checks and can be installed directly from github

*`npm install --save yup yup-phone`*.

Check [Usage](http://yup-phone.js.org/)

```
const Yup = require('yup');
require('yup-phone');

// validate any phone number (defaults to India for country)
const phoneSchema = Yup.string().phone().required();
phoneSchema.isValid('9876543210'); // → true
```

---

---

From [**Simple React Validator**](https://github.com/dockwa/simple-react-validator/blob/master/src/simple-react-validator.js#L42),

The regex for phone number validation is

```
/^(\+?\d{0,4})?\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{4}\)?)?$/
```

### **Example**

```
// index.js

const yup = require('yup');
const { rePhoneNumber } = require('./yup-phone')

const schema = yup.string().phone()

const phone = '+911234567890';
console.log('Is Valid? ', rePhoneNumber.test(phone)); // Is Valid? true
schema.validateSync(phone);
```

---

```
// yup-phone.js

const yup = require('yup');

const rePhoneNumber = /^(\+?\d{0,4})?\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{4}\)?)?$/;

module.exports.rePhoneNumber = rePhoneNumber

yup.addMethod(yup.string, "phone", function() {
  return this.test("phone", "Phone number is not valid", value =>
    rePhoneNumber.test(value)
  );
});
```

---

Comment: unless I've missed something along the way, I have not been able to pass validation for a blank field.  That is, I only want to validate if a value is present.

Comment: I originally gave this an upvote. However, the bundle size is larger than my entire website. Do not use it on the frontend

Comment: I tried to use yup-phone here -- https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-phone-validation-forked-ixgnjj  -- but it will allow numbers with ++ at the front? -- "++33343335678"

Comment: even google-lib phone allowed this -- https://codesandbox.io/s/google-phone-lib-demo-forked-k29kk8  "+++33343335678"

Answer (score 12):

Try this, it might be helpful for you.

```
mobile: Yup.string().matches(/^[6-9]\d{9}$/, {message: "Please enter valid number.", excludeEmptyString: false})
```

Comment: it wouldn't validate phone numbers starting with digits 1-5

Comment: yes @RahilAhmad, usually in India mobile numbers starts with either 6 or 7 or 8 or 9, so regex validates those numbers only.

Comment: It allows number starting with 0

Answer (score 12):

```js
const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/


phone_number: Yup.string()
  .required("required")
  .matches(phoneRegExp, 'Phone number is not valid')
  .min(10, "too short")
  .max(10, "too long"),
```

This works best for me...you can set your own length...i just wanted 10 digits not less or more

Answer (score 4):

Just a little collaboration. On my case I don't want to validate if the input is empty (when is not required). Thank you all for your examples!

```
yup.addMethod(yup.string, "phone", function(messageError = 'Phone number is not valid') {
    const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/
    return this.test('phone', messageError, value => {
      if (value && value.length > 0) {
        return phoneRegExp.test(value)
      }
      return true
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar with .transform(). Is it more appropriate to use .test()?

Answer (score 2):

I made a new package for this called [yup-phone-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup-phone-lite).  I had used the original yup-phone package but it uses the massive google-libphonenumber so I replaced it with a smaller fork.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use case, and here's my solution:

```
// Regex source: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s02.html

const phoneRegex = RegExp(
  /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/
);

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  phone: yup.string().matches(phoneRegex, "Invalid phone").required("Phone is required")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from my code.

```
let schema = yup.object().shape({
  phone: yup
    .string()
    // regexr.com/6anqd
    .matches(/(\+91\ )[6-9]{1}[0-9 ]{4}[0-9 ]{4}[0-9]{3}/, {
      message: "Invalid Indian number",
      excludeEmptyString: false,
    })
    .required(),
  email: yup.string().required().email(),
  password: yup.string().required().min(8),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .required()
    .oneOf([yup.ref("password")], "Passwords do not match"),
  agree: yup
    .boolean()
    .oneOf(
      [true],
      "It is essential to accept our Privacy Policy to register.",
    ),
});
```

[My regex](https://regexr.com/6anqd) checks for Indian Phone numbers following the format, `+91 axxx xxx xxx` (where `a` can be a digit in the range 6 to 9 and `x` can be 0 - 9).

I tried [yup-home](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup-phone) but it was not able to actually verify the range for the Indian Number I wanted, plus, the package import size was costly.

---

Also, I'm using React with Formik at the frontend for form validation with [react-phone-input-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2)

```
<PhoneInput
  country={"in"}
  value={values.phone}
  name="phone"
  onChange={(phone, data, e) => handleChange(e)}
  onBlur={(e) => handleBlur(e)}
  defaultMask=".... ... ..."
  masks={{ in: ".... ... ..." }}
  onlyCountries={["in"]}
  inputProps={{
    name: "phone",
    required: true,
    autoFocus: true,
  }}
  disableSearchIcon={true}
  disableDropdown={true}
  containerClass="mt-1 border h-12 text-sm focus:outline-none block w-full bg-gray-100 dark:bg-transparent border-transparent focus:bg-white"
  inputClass="mt-1 border h-12 text-sm focus:outline-none block w-full bg-gray-100 dark:bg-transparent border-transparent focus:bg-white"
  inputStyle={{
    background: "transparent",
    border: "1px solid grey",
    height: "3em",
    width: "100%",
    outline: "none",
  }}
  buttonStyle={{
    height: "3em",
    background: "transparent",
    outline: "none",
    border: "none",
  }}
/>
{handleFormikError(errors, touched, "phone")} // returns the span.alert with error message
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I combined yup with other 3rd phone validation libraries ("awesome-phonenumber" in my case):

```js
import { parsePhoneNumber } from "awesome-phonenumber";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  phoneNumber: Yup.string()
    .required("Required")
    .test("phoneNumber", "Phone number is not valid", (str, context) => {
      const pn = parsePhoneNumber(str);
      return pn.valid;
    }),
  addressLine1: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  // ...Other fields
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, This is regex for indian local mobile number validation and for Indian international .**

starting with 9,8,7 you can add more as well.

**you can test it using https://regex101.com/**

```
import * as Yup from "yup";

const phoneNumberRules = /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/;

const emailRules = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(gmail|yahoo)\.com$/;

export const clientSchema=Yup.object().shape({

    name:Yup.string().required("Name Not be Empty"),

    email: Yup.string().email("Invalid Email!")
      .matches(emailRules, { message: " Not valid :{" })
      .required("Email Required !"),

      phone: Yup.string()
      .matches(phoneNumberRules, { message: "Invalid Phone Number!" })
      .required("Phone Number Required !"),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, phone number is an optional field and I didn't want to care about a complex pattern. So I used the test method with a simple regex

```
yup.string().test('phone', `Invalid phone number`, (v) => {
  if (!v) {
    return true;
  }
  return /^\+?\d{6,15}$/.test(v);
});
```

- accept "+" symbol
- min 6 digits
- max 15 digits